# weblogic : Connection has already been closed error using connection pool

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am using connection pool of weblogic but its giving below error log even though I am closing connection in `finally` each time.

I checked in weblogic monitoring there is failed reserve request time count is 4970

Is there any solution to get only opened connections all time?

```
  [ERROR] 2020-08-31 08:16:05,815 com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO details - hrer1
[ERROR] 2020-08-31 08:16:05,815 com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO details - connction issue
[ERROR] 2020-08-31 08:16:05,934 com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO details - connction issue
[ERROR] 2020-08-31 08:16:05,944 com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO details - Connection has already been closed.
java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.checkConnection(PoolConnection.java:99)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.checkStatement(Statement.java:323)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.preInvocationHandler(Statement.java:123)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.setInt(PreparedStatement.java:529)
        at com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO.details(ResponseDAO.java:810)
        at com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO.getDetail(ResponseDAO.java:1434)
        at com.org.fwd.services.responseservice.responsedetails(responseservice.java:280)
        at com.org.fwd.controller.getDetailcontroller.stepdetailcontroller(getDetailcontroller.java:107)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1644.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:274)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
[ERROR] 2020-08-31 08:16:05,945 com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO details - hrer1
[ERROR] 2020-08-31 08:16:05,945 com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO details - connction issue
[ERROR] 2020-08-31 08:16:05,948 com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO details - connction issue
[ERROR] 2020-08-31 08:16:05,963 com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO details - Connection has already been closed.
java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PoolConnection.checkConnection(PoolConnection.java:112)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet.preInvocationHandler(ResultSet.java:93)
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_ForwardOnlyResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
        at com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO.details(ResponseDAO.java:838)
        at com.org.fwd.dao.ResponseDAO.getDetail(ResponseDAO.java:1445)
        at com.org.fwd.services.responseservice.responsedetails(responseservice.java:280)
        at com.org.fwd.controller.getDetailcontroller.stepdetailcontroller(getDetailcontroller.java:107)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1644.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:274)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

code that I am using as below

```
'

     public ArrayList<Response> getDetail(int id, int count) throws SQLException{
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ArrayList<Integer> IdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            DConnection dsobj = new DConnection(dbinstance);
            con = (java.sql.Connection) dsobj.getConnection();

    
        String sql = "select id from id_table  where id=" + id + " order by entry_date";
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            // System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
            IdList.add(rs.getInt(1));

        }
    {
            int chunks = IdList.size() / 5;
            if (count == 1) {

                ArrayList<Response> response = new ArrayList<Response>();

                for (int i = 0; i < Math.round(chunks); i++) {
                    response.add(details(IdList.get(i).toString(), con));
                }

                return response;

            }
            if (count == 2) {
                ArrayList<Response> response = new ArrayList<Response>();

                for (int i = Math.round(chunks); i < Math.round(chunks) * 2; i++) {
                    response.add(details(IdList.get(i).toString(), con));

                }
                return response;

            }
            if (count == 3) {

                ArrayList<Response> response = new ArrayList<Response>();

                for (int i = Math.round(chunks) * 2; i < Math.round(chunks) * 3; i++) {
                    response.add(details(IdList.get(i).toString(), con));

                }
                return response;

            }
            if (count == 4) {

                ArrayList<Response> response = new ArrayList<Response>();

                for (int i = Math.round(chunks) * 3; i < Math.round(chunks) * 4; i++) {
                    response.add(details(IdList.get(i).toString(), con));

                }
                return response;

            }
            if (count == 5) {

                ArrayList<Response> response = new ArrayList<Response>();

                for (int i = Math.round(chunks) * 4; i < IdList.size(); i++) {
                    response.add(details(IdList.get(i).toString(), con));

                }
                return response;

            }       }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
logger.error(e1.getMessage(),e1);       
e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(con!=null)
            {try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
        }
        return null;
    }


    public Response details(String s, Connection con) {
        ResultSet RS1 = null;
        ResultSet RS2 = null;
        ResultSet RS3 = null;
        ResultSet RS4 = null;
        CallableStatement callStmt = null;
        ArrayList<input> input = new ArrayList<input>();
        ArrayList<output> output = new ArrayList<output>();
        ArrayList<sub> sub = new ArrayList<sub>();
        H1 hd=null;
    //  CallableStatement callStmt1 = null,callStmt2 = null;

    
        try {
            if (con == null) {
                logger.error("connction issue");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            callStmt = con.prepareCall("{call data.getdetails(?,?,?,?,?)}");

            callStmt.setString(1, s);
            callStmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            callStmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            callStmt.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            callStmt.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

            callStmt.execute();

            RS1 = (ResultSet) callStmt.getObject(2); 
            RS2 = (ResultSet) callStmt.getObject(3); 
            RS3 = (ResultSet) callStmt.getObject(4); 
            RS4 = (ResultSet) callStmt.getObject(5);
            RS1.next();
            String desc = RS1.getString(1);

            String[] descArr = desc.split("#\\$@");
        
            int id=Integer.parseInt(descArr[8]);
            String clr = "";
            CallableStatement callStmt2;
            ***callStmt2 = con.prepareCall("{call data.getda(?,?)}");*** 
            callStmt2.setInt(1, id);
            callStmt2.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            callStmt2.execute();
            clr=callStmt2.getString(2);
            callStmt2.close();
            if(clr.equals("P")) {
                clr="pink";
            }
            else if(clr.equals("R")) {
                clr="red";
            }
            else {
                clr="black";
            }
        //  System.out.println(clr);
             hd = new H1(Integer.parseInt(descArr[0]), descArr[1],
                    descArr[2], descArr[3], descArr[4], descArr[5], descArr[6], descArr[7],
                    Integer.parseInt(descArr[8]),clr);

        
            while (RS2.next()) {
                // String IP = RS2.getString(1);
                String IP = RS2.getString(1) + " " + "#*@";
                String[] IPArr = IP.split("#\\*@");
            //  System.out.println(IPArr.length);
                String colour = "black";
                String ipname=IPArr[2];
                if(ipname!=null) {
                    CallableStatement callStmt1;
                    callStmt1 = con.prepareCall("{call data.getclr1(?,?,?)}"); // Calling
                     callStmt1.setInt(1, id);
             callStmt1.setString(2, IPArr[2]);
                     callStmt1.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                     callStmt1.execute();
                     colour=callStmt1.getString(3);
                     callStmt1.close();
                }
                
                input.add(new input((Integer.parseInt(IPArr[1])), IPArr[2],
                        IPArr[3], IPArr[4], IPArr[5], IPArr[6], IPArr[7],
                        (IPArr[8]), (IPArr[9]), (IPArr[10]), IPArr[11],
                        IPArr[12], colour));
            }
            RS2.close();
            while (RS3.next()) {
                String OP = RS3.getString(1) + " " + "#*@";

            //  String OP = RS3.getString(1);
                String[] OPArr = OP.split("#\\*@");
            //  System.out.println(OPArr.length);
                output.add(new output((Integer.parseInt(OPArr[1])), OPArr[2],
                        OPArr[3], OPArr[4], OPArr[5], OPArr[6], OPArr[7],
                        OPArr[8], (OPArr[9]), (OPArr[10]), (OPArr[11]),
                        OPArr[12]));

            }
            RS3.close();

            RS4.next();
            sub subName = new sub(RS4.getString(1));
            sub.add(subName);
            RS4.close();
            return new Response(hd, input, output, sub);

            // hdresponse1.add(new hdresponse(hd,input));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (callStmt != null)
                    callStmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        logger.error("hrer1");
        return null;
    }

'
```

And data size is around 3 MB for 1 JSON file

Comment: If you are sure that you sometimes get closed connection from the connection pool you can enable the "test connection on reserve" in the pool configuration. It will ensure that the connection is alive before it is given to the application.

Comment: Yes i tried that option also but no luck..

Comment: That could mean that your application code does not handle connections correctly, can you post your code ?

Comment: Can you post also the complete stack trace plz.

Comment: done.. Thanks you!! if you want anything else i can provide

Comment: Thx. Can you highlight the line #838 in the code you have posted.

Comment: this code line is not present in the code you have pasted...
How long does it take to your code to execute all sql requests and get results ?
Do you have a firewall between your application server and your database ?

Comment: sorry correct line is callStmt2 = con.prepareCall("{call data.getda(?,?)}"); ' ..it takes around 3-4 minutes and no there is no firewall..

Comment: is it possible that connection is not getting closed even after calling close on connection

Comment: 3/4 minutes is very very long. You may have a read timeout set on your connection that could explain why it is closed in the middle of your run.

Comment: oh.. thanks.. when data is lesser it returns in seconds ..is there way to increase it throgh code ..if you know

Comment: one more thing that i noticed in weblogic is active connection current count goes to around 248 and stucks there when result, fails, incase of success, it gradually goes down to 2 or 3 and my connection pool size is 800

Comment: The timeout is settable at the jdbc driver level. Refer to its documentation and find which property should be set to increase the read timeout.